# How to remove MDI buttons from an MDI form?

Tags: delphi

I am using MDI forms and in the main form I have a MainMenu or ActionMainMenuBar, I would like to maximize the child form the system buttons of that form would not appear in the menu bar.

Comment: Pity the poor user that is then unable to restore the window. These buttons are there for a reason. Without them your program becomes unusable.

Comment: Can you give us the code you achieved yet so we can give decent examples of ways to do what you ask ?

Comment: Do you want the child forms to be always maximized? If so, you don't need MDI but [TDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_(GUI)).

Comment: I'm using TAdvOfficeMDITabset to create a TDI application, but the problem is that I need to remove the system's MDI form buttons because the form control uses another approach with my own controls.